# Typing into Windows 10 Edge date input?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

The default date picker used by Windows 10 Edge browser appears to only allow for scrolling through the M/D/Y parts. Does anyone know of a way to configure the HTML to allow for direct typing into the control?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I've logged it here for the Microsoft Edge Dev team to take a look: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1712208/edge-date-input-element-does-not-allow-direct-input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want at this point.  I would suggest you submit a feature suggestion at Feature Suggestions -
   https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/category/18985-web-browsing .

Some other areas to supply feedback on Microsoft Edge.

- Bugs for Edge and IE - https://connect.microsoft.com/ie/feedback
- Developer Feedback Home -
  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer
- Developer Feedback Twitter - https://www.twitter.com/msedgedev

Hope that helps.  Healy in Tampa.

Comment: 2017, still the same.

Comment: 2018, still the same.

Comment: My solution for now: detecting if it's IE/Edge using https://stackoverflow.com/a/38323604/808824 and then applying a jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: 2019, still the same

Comment: 2020, still the same