# form not submitting in Microsoft Edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, microsoft-edge

In Rails 5 application I have a form  which is not being submitted correctly on Edge, due to submit input being placed outside of the form. Is there any way I can handle it without changing my html structure to actually have input inside the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that if you don't want to move the submit button into the form (although I don't really understand why would you want the button to be outside of `<form>` tags), you can submit the form by Javascript.

Just call `submit` method on form after the button has been clicked. Using jQuery, it would look something like this:

```
$("#my-button").on("click", function() {
  $("my-form").submit();
});
```

Comment: and how do i do that for Edge only?

Comment: Theoretically you could run the Javascript code only if user's browser is edge. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721250/how-to-target-windows-10-edge-browser-with-javascript for example. BUT I would strongly recommend against doing so. Submit the form in same way across all browsers.