# how to select only edge and IE >= 10 on javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to create a javascript code only for the edge and internet explorer or even a 10. I only find information for internet explorer

```
        var isIE = document.body.style.msTouchAction !== undefined;
if(isIE ){// stuff }
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153542). **Why** do you want to detect IE and Edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target Windows 10 Edge browser with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721250/how-to-target-windows-10-edge-browser-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser Hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) shows [`var isIE = window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;`](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-2f32c95ac8c021c463de0fdf685acb29) as a solution.

And actually, it shows what you have as well. According to them, it works for IE10+ and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is described in a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938396/1501985.

To quote the link (in short):

**Using a parser library**

```
# https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js.

var parser = new UAParser();
var result = parser.getResult();

var name = result.browser.name;
var version = result.browser.version;
```

**Raw Javascript approach**

```
# Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
# Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136

window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1
```

Comment: I think the idea is to avoid user agent sniffing since it can be spoofed.

Comment: I understand how that can be a concern, but I don't read this as a constraint by the original poster. In addition, anything, which relies on the client as master of data, can be spoofed by the user.